# Instapy Crashes as soon as it gets to users account

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, instapy

Hello I used instapy about a year ago and it worked great. However since I have been trying to use it recently I have ran into some issues. I am using the basic_follow-unfollow_activity quickstart template. This template always crashes as soon as I get to the users followers. Below I have the errors that I get when it crashes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Likel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\instapy\unfollow_util.py", line 661, in get_users_through_dialog_with_graphql
    user_id = browser.execute_script(
  File "C:\Users\Likel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "C:\Users\Likel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Likel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: window.__additionalData[Object.keys(...)[0]] is undefined


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Likel\instapy-quickstart-master\instapy-quickstart-master\quickstart_templates\basic_follow-unfollow_activity.py", line 52, in <module>
    session.follow_user_followers(['luke._5', 'usuclassof2025'], amount=800,
  File "C:\Users\Likel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 3675, in follow_user_followers
    person_list, simulated_list = get_given_user_followers(
  File "C:\Users\Likel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\instapy\unfollow_util.py", line 1003, in get_given_user_followers
    person_list, simulated_list = get_users_through_dialog_with_graphql(
  File "C:\Users\Likel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\instapy\unfollow_util.py", line 665, in get_users_through_dialog_with_graphql
    user_id = browser.execute_script(
  File "C:\Users\Likel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "C:\Users\Likel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Likel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: window._sharedData.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].graphql is undefined
```